# Adding data to estimote beacons advertisement packet in android

Tags: android, ibeacon, estimote

Is it possible to add additional data from our side apart from the predefined UUID, major, minor and mpower values to the estimote beacons?

I want to add my empirically calculated constants of RSSI to distance formula in beacon's advertisement packets as well so that the formula is more reliable in that given environment and my app in user mobiles can get this data to use it in calculating the distance instead of the default one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, you cannot add additional fields to an iBeacon transmission** besides the standard ProiximityUUID, major, minor and calibratedTxPower fields.

While it is certainly possible to build your own custom beacon hardware that sends other fields, **there is an easier way to accomplish the same end goal.**  Simply use a web service to return these constants based on a look up of the uuid/major/minor.  This solution requires an internet connection, but otherwise accomplishes the same thing.